# NuGet restore fails with "Package contains multiple nuspec files" on my machine only

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

I am using VS2015U3 and NuGet 3.4.4. running on Windows 10 Anniversary Update.
NuGet restore gives this error when run in Visual Studio or when run on the command line.

I've tested this on two independent solution files with the same results. However the build server and my laptop restore packages without any problem.

I've tried downloading NuGet.exe fresh, repairing Visual Studio, Uninstalling and Reinstalling the NuGet Package manager and clearing the NuGet cache.

Here is the output from running NuGet restore ..\mySolution.sln on the command line:

Restoring NuGet package RestSharp.102.7.0.
Restoring NuGet package Rx-Core.2.2.5.
Restoring NuGet package Rx-Interfaces.2.2.5.
Restoring NuGet package Newtonsoft.Json.4.0.8.
Restoring NuGet package Rx-Linq.2.2.5.
Restoring NuGet package Rx-Main.2.2.5.
Restoring NuGet package Rx-PlatformServices.2.2.5.
Restoring NuGet package Rx-WPF.2.2.5.
Restoring NuGet package Rx-XAML.2.2.5.
Restoring NuGet package LiveCharts.0.6.5.
Restoring NuGet package CommandLineParser.1.9.71.
WARNING: Package contains multiple nuspec files.

Errors in packages.config projects
    Package contains multiple nuspec files.

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
    C:\ProgramData\nuget\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

Feeds used:
    C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
    C:\Users\Rob.nuget\packages\
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\

Answer (score 4):

Running "Nuget.exe locals all -clear" fixed this

Comment: In my case nuget didn't have command locals, but it worked with "nuget restore"